# Function field analogy

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, function-fields

I am rephrasing the previous question:
Can I get good and accessible references to read to understand this particular statement in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function_field#Number_fields_and_finite_fields): "*The function field analogy states that almost all theorems on number fields have a counterpart on function fields of one variable over a finite field, and these counterparts are frequently easier to prove.*"

Comment: See the answer given on [this book title](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780817643973): "Ever since the analogy between number fields and function fields was discovered, it has been a source of inspiration for new ideas." For a better answer you need to  be more precise about "multivariate extension".

Comment: If I phrase the question as "how can we define a multivariate extension to see properties of number fields have analogues in that multivariate extension ", can I see some examples. I am not very clear myself, but I am hoping examples will make it clearer for me.

Comment: I would refer you to Helmut Hasse's "Number Theory". He essentially develops algebraic number theory from scratch and at the end of every chapter does the same constructions for function fields. For function fields, it's good to learn from the OG German function field gang

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Who are the people in the OG function field gang?

Comment: People like Hasse, Artin, Schmidt, F.K.Schmidt and more